# I want to hide the row number column in QTableWidget

Tags: c++, qt

Normal QTablewidget is as follows:

```
          a             b
1        data          data
2        data          data
3        data          data
```

I want to remove the first column that shows row numbers.
My table should look like this:

```
  a             b
data          data
data          data
data          data
```

I can not find the way to do this. Let me know if there is a way to add items more easily.
That 's how I implemented my table:

```
QString a[5];
    a[0]="ddd";
QTableWidgetItem *item1 = new QTableWidgetItem(a[0]);
ui->tableWidget->setItem(0,0,item1 );
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are two views in `QTable` the **vertical and the horizontal header**, they are defined in `QTableView`, as any widget you can hide them so it can be done as below :

```
ui->tableWidget->verticalHeader()->setVisible(false); // Get Vertical header and hide it
```

You can have vertical header in easy way as one line code,

```
ui->tableWidget->setHorizontalHeaderLabels(QString("HEADER 1;HEADER 2;HEADER 3;HEADER 4").split(";"));
```

For setting the data in Table you can use `QString Array` which contains data using `for` loop you can store the data in table, but you need to take care about indexing.

Comment: @백자현 :   if it worked for you then accept the answer, so that it will be useful for others when come across the same question !!

Comment: @Amol Nobody thinks about verticalHeader() API . This is useful information. +1

Comment: but That way is to place the order , How to determine row ?

Comment: @백자현 :  eg. You will set item in table as `table->setItem(0,0,new QTableWidgetItem("ITEM_1-1"));`  , then first parameter is row then column

Comment: I will try to give answer to the questions another person just like you